# Angular2: Can I process @Output return value with arrow function instead of method

Tags: angular, angular2-template, arrow-functions, angular2-databinding

I have an Angular2 app which has a parent component (AppComponent) and several child components. One of them (DnDContainer) has an @Output variable like this:

```
@Output() onDataUpdate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Inside DnDContainer, there is a button with the following code in its click event:

```
onSave(e) {
   this.onDataUpdate.emit(this.data);
   // this.data is just a simple string array
}
```

Then, from the AppComponent, there are several DnDContainer components (their selector is 'dnd-container'). I'd like to listen to their 'onDataUpdate' output and assign it to a different array (targetItemsA, targetItemsB, etc). I'm trying to use a simple syntax like this:

```
<dnd-container (onDataUpdate)="($event) => {targetItemsA = $event}"></dnd-container>
<dnd-container (onDataUpdate)="($event) => {targetItemsB = $event}"></dnd-container>
```

But it doesn't work, so I had to create an specific method just for assigning an array to another one, like this:

```
<dnd-container [onDataUpdate)="update('A', $event)"></dnd-container>
<dnd-container [onDataUpdate)="update('B', $event)"></dnd-container>
```

The method looks like:

```
update(which, data) {
  switch (which) {
   case 'A':
     this.targetItemsA=data;
     break;
   case 'B':
     this.targetItemsB=data;
     break;
   case 'C':
     this.targetItemsC=data;
     break;
   (ETC...)
  }
}
```

Is there any simpler way to do this (like the one with arrow function I pointed at the beginning)? Sorry if it's too basic, I'm quite new to Angular2.

Thanks in advance,

PS: On the tsconfig.spec.json file, I've changed the 'target' property to 'es6' but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `<dnd-container (onDataUpdate)="targetItemsA = $event"></dnd-container>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes:

```
@Output() onDataUpdate: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
```

Try to avoid using `any` if you know the type that will be emitted.

In the app component you have two options: create a function to handle the event (cleaner template), or directly make operations in it. Apparently you dont want to create a method so the following should work:

```
<dnd-container (onDataUpdate)="targetItemsA = $event"></dnd-container>
```

Comment: Glad to help :), if this solved your question, please mark it as answer so that others can see it if they come across your question